# Retrieve historical data from the Citrix Director

Tags: powershell, session, citrix

We would like to have a list of all users that used a specific Citrix published desktop. Apparently this can be done within the Citrix Director tool but we would like to have this automated with PowerShell.

The following Citrix CmdLet exposes the data we need but [only for the last 48 hours](https://citrix.github.io/delivery-controller-sdk/Broker/Get-BrokerConnectionLog/):

```bsh
Get-BrokerConnectionLog
```

How would it be possible to retreive this data for the last 2 months for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Platinum / Premium edition you can set the retention periods for different data.

Look at Get-MonitorConfiguration to see the retention time and Set-MonitorConfiguration to set what you need.

https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2016/12/16/extended-monitoring-data-retention-for-enterprise-customers-with-citrix-director-7-12/